# What Is wrong with my elasticsearch query implemented via firestore callable function?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have connected to elasticsearch, and I have created index `users`. I want to be able to search that index based on a query. I followed the example from firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=elastic) where they write the query in the following way:

```
exports.searchNotes = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const query = data.query;

  const searchRes = await client.search({
    index: "notes",
    body: {
      query: {
        query_string: {
          query: `*${query}*`,
          fields: [
            "text"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const hits = searchRes.body.hits.hits;

  const notes = hits.map(h => h["_source"]);
  return {
    notes: notes
  };
});
```

So I changed very few things and my initial query looked like this:

```
exports.searchUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log("on search users");
  const query = data.query;
  console.log("my query: ", query)

  const searchRes = await client.search({
    index: "users",
    body: {
      query: {
        query_string: {
          query: `*${query}*`,
          fields: [
            "text"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(() => console.log("do I actually go here?"))
    .catch((error) => console.log("what is my actuall error: ", error));

  console.log("how does it look like: ", searchRes);
   const hits = searchRes.hits.hits;
   const users = hits.map(h => h["_source"]);
   console.log("how users looks like: ", users);
   return {
     users: users
   };
});
```

Which gave me an error because `searchRes` are undefined. When I go to sirestore functions logs, I can see "my query" being displayed, I also see ""do I actually go here?")" but thats all. Why I dont see any users, even empty list?

Comment: Don't mix async/await with then/catch.  Just use one or the other when dealing with promises, and prefer async/await for readability.

Comment: OK, I will try only with async await and see if there is any difference